# Count Number of Slots for Balls with Repetition

Tags: combinatorics

I have $3$ slots and $3$ balls. Each ball needs to go into a slot, but each slot does not need to be used. By writing out all of the possibilities, I know there are $27$ possible combinations.

For example,

$$000$$

$$001$$

$$002$$

$$010$$

$$011$$

$$012$$

$$...$$

However, is there some sort of formula that can be used to apply this to larger problems where we can't write all of them out? Just straight permutation and combination doesn't seem to give the correct number, nor does factorial. All of these are assuming you want to use each slot, but in my case I can leave $n-1$ slots empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine the balls and urns are numbered. The first ball must go into one of the three urns, hence we have $3$ alternatives. For each one of those alternatives, we have $3$ new alternatives for the second ball, etc. Hence we have $3 \times 3 \times 3 = 3^3$ ways. In general, if we have $B$ balls and $X$ urns we have $X^B$ ways.

More in general, see the [rule of product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product)